# Matrix equation transformation

Tags: derivatives, transformation, matrix-equations

Let's consider the following differential equation
$$
\frac{dA}{dt} + A \cdot X = 0,
$$
where $A(t)$ and $X(t)$ are $N \times N$ matrices.

I'm looking for a $A \rightarrow B$ substitution which transforms this equation to the form
$$
\frac{dB}{dt} + X \cdot B = 0.
$$

One's first intuition is to use $A = B^{-1}$, then we have
$$
-B^{-1} \cdot \frac{dB}{dt} \cdot B^{-1} + B^{-1} \cdot X = 0.
$$
Multiplying the last equality by $B$ from both sides we obtain
$$
\frac{dB}{dt} - X \cdot B = 0.
$$
But in the final expression the sign at $X \cdot B$ is changed.

Can one propose an appropriate transformation or show that it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case $$X = \pmatrix{ 1/(t+1) & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$
The solution of $\dfrac{dA}{dt} = X(t) A(t)$ with $A(0) = I$ is
$$ A(t) = \pmatrix{(1+t)\ln(1+t) & 1+t\cr
                     1 & 0\cr}$$
The solution of $\dfrac{dB}{dt} = B(t) X(t)$ with $B(0)=I$ is
$$ B(t) = \pmatrix{t + 1 & t^2/2 + t\cr 0 & 1\cr}$$

There is no nice transformation that takes $A(t)$ to $B(t)$ or vice versa.
In particular, the entries of $B(t)$ are polynomials while those of $A(t)$ are not all analytic.

EDIT:
Similarly, if you take $X_{12} = e^t$ instead of $1$, you get an example where all entries of $B(t)$ are elementary functions, but one of the entries of $A$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Take $B = A^T$.  By taking the transpose of both sides, we see that
$$
\frac{dA^T}{dt} + X^T\cdot A^T = 0
$$

Comment: ... except that the OP wanted $X$, not $X^T$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the difficulty is to conserve the initial form of $X$. $X^{T}$ does not fit.